# Python pass argument to constructor by reference

Tags: python, oop

```
import pandas as pd

class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, df):
        self.df = df

    def edit(self):
        self.df = self.df[~self.df['numbers'].isin([2,4,6,8,10])]

df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], columns=['numbers'])
obj = MyClass(df).edit()
print df
```

I am expecting `print df` to print the dataframe which has been reassigned after the filteration function.

But this stil prints the dataframe which is before the `edit` function modify it.

How can my outer variable still track the changes happend to the `df` inside class

Comment: Strings are immutable. `var` will not change until you reassign the name.

Comment: ok in actual it is a `pandas datafare`. should i change it to list to keep it simple ?

Comment: I don't know because I don't see the point of your class at all. If you want to mutate a mutable object, why not use the methods it exposes directly?

Comment: Also, it is considered an anti-pattern to globally modify arguments of functions inside the function, let alone arguments used as "initializes". Imagine trying to debug a program with several "`var`" variables and `MyClass` instances.

Comment: I am updating the actual problem which will make more sense.

Comment: FYI your code would "work" if you made `var = [1,2,3]` and changed the body of `edit` to `self.var.pop()`, for example.

Comment: @timgeb that was the simulation. Can you please see the question now. It is not list but pandas dataframe.

Comment: You have to mutate the variable. *assignment is not mutation*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can my outer variable still track the changes happend to the df inside class

The way you are trying to do this, namely by reassignment, it's impossible. Names do not "see" the reassignment of other names (imagine the catastrophe if they did).

Your only chance without reassigning `df` here is to *mutate* the dataframe. All you currently do is to create a new object and reassign `self.var`. The `var` outside of your class does not care about that and still points to the old object.

Of course the sensible thing to do would be to just reassign `df` to the return value of some function or method, i.e.:

```
def compute_new_df_from_old_df(df):
    return df.foo()[bar]

df = <some dataframe>
df = compute_new_df_from_old_df(df)
```

Comment: Actually the `var` outside is responsbile to call other stuff such as `var.to_csv()` so that is why i needed the var to be in final state

Answer (score 1):

Try rewriting your code as:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], columns=['numbers'])
obj = MyClass(df)
obj.edit()
print obj.df
```

Comment: Probably i can save alot of time by this rather than going to the whole refactor

Comment: As I said, reassign. `df = obj.df` or  `df = obj.edit()` if you make `obj.edit` `return` the dataframe.

Comment: @suresh Thanks for the answer. I accepted the above answer because It explains the bigger picture.

Comment: You are welcome. Many times code is the best vehicle to explain.

Answer (score 0):

Immutable objects aren't passed by reference (and technically, [neither are mutable objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference)). Is there any specific reason you want to do this?

Comment: Sorry, I was trying ti simulate the problem i was having. I have updated the question now can you please check